# WSL Failed to Initialize on Windows 11

Tags: docker, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed Docker on a clean laptop with the official Windows 11 with the latest update. Pre-installed WSL2 for Windows 11 according to Microsoft documentation. When running docker, the "docker starting..." is infinite. Attaching the error log.
Error sending starting WSL engine:

> Docker.Core.HttpBadResponseException: {"message":"2 errors
> occurred:\n\t* provisioning docker WSL distros: unregistering WSL
> distro "docker-desktop": unregistering WSL "docker-desktop":
> winapi error #2147746562\n\t* checking if isocache exists: CreateFile
> \\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\isocache\: The network name cannot be
> found.\n\n"}

I tried to reinstall WSL and Docker. Deleted %appdata%/docker.
For the test, I tried to install the Ubuntu subsystem through the Microsoft store. She didn't work either. Most likely a problem with the WSL. Tried to disable and enable again Windows features (WSL Support and Virtual Machine feature).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same error solved it by: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/7039

Don't need to reinstall it.

Open windows shell as Administrator and run:

```powershell
wsl --unregister docker-desktop
```

Then go to *services*, stop *Docker Desktop* service, then start it again.

Comment: a thousand thank yous to you, sir!  may you live a long and happy life.